# Passing methods between components in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, methods, components

I have started learning ReactJs recently and I want some help. I've created two components in my project. The first one is MainComponent and it looks as follows:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onDishSelect = this.onDishSelect.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      dishes: DISHES,
      selectedDish: null
    };
  }

  onDishSelect(dishId) {
    this.setState({ selectedDish: dishId });
  }
```

The other component which is the child component is called Menu and I used the event handler onClick to call the method "onDishSelect" which exists in the Parent class, "Main". This is what I exactly did in the parent component to get the method invoked within the event handler Onclick:

```
onClick={() => this.onDishSelect(dish)
```

I added this as a property in my child component to use the method from the parent component. I know there is something missing in my code. Yet, I can't handle it. I want a way to use a method without writing this method again in the child component.

I'd appreciate any help to get through this as I spent much time for no reason but this. Thanks in advance.

P.s. This is my main component and my menu component code:

```
class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onDishSelect = this.onDishSelect.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      dishes: DISHES,
      selectedDish: null
    };
  }

  onDishSelect(dishId) {
    this.setState({ selectedDish: dishId });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar dark color="danger">
          <div className="container">
            <NavbarBrand href="/">Elite Café</NavbarBrand>
          </div>
        </Navbar>
        <Menu
          dishes={this.state.dishes}
          selectedDish={this.state.selectedDish}
          onClick={dishId => this.onDishSelect(dishId)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

--Menu component code:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import {
  Media,
  Card,
  CardImg,
  CardText,
  CardBody,
  CardTitle,
  CardImgOverlay
} from "reactstrap";
import DishDetail from "./dishDetailsComponent";

class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  onDishSelect(dish) {
    this.setState({ selectedDish: dish });
  }
  renderDish(dish) {
    if (dish != null) {
      return (
        <Card className="col-12 col-md-5 col-sm-12 m-1 border-0">
          {/* <CardImg width="100%" object src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
          <CardBody className="cardBody">
            <CardTitle>
              <strong>{dish.name}</strong>
            </CardTitle>
            <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText> */}
          <DishDetail
            className="cardBody"
            selectedDish={this.state.selectedDish}
            dishes={this.props.dishes}
          />
          {/* </CardBody> */}
        </Card>
      );
    } else {
      return <div />;
    }
  }
  renderComments(dish) {
    if (dish != null) {
      return (
        <ul className="list-unstyled ml-1">
          <div className="col-12 col-md-10">
            <li>
              <strong>Comments</strong>
            </li>
            {dish.comments.map((item, id) => (
              <div key={id} className="mt-1">
                <div className="mb-2">{item.comment}</div>
                <li>
                  {" "}
                  <div>
                    -- {item.author}, {item.date}
                  </div>
                </li>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </ul>
      );
    } else {
      return <div />;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const menu = this.props.dishes.map(dish => {
      return (
        <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
          <Card onClick={() => this.onDishSelect(dish)}>
            <CardImg width="100%" object src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
            <CardImgOverlay>
              <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
            </CardImgOverlay>
          </Card>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          {menu}
          {this.renderDish(this.state.selectedDish)}
          {this.renderComments(this.state.selectedDish)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu;
```

Comment: Can you add the part of the code where the child is being called?

Comment: I edited the post. Kindly take a look.

Comment: You are passing the function `onDishSelect` as `onClick` to the Menu / child component. It can be accessed by `this.props.onClick(dishId)` inside Menu, if its a class component or `props.onClick(disId)` if the Menu is functional component.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Would you pls tell me where I should exactly add this line? I am a little bit confused.

Comment: It can be added inside the child component from where you have to access the function. It'll be helpful to answer if you could add the Menu component also.

Comment: It is added now. Would you pls take a look.

Answer (score 0):

In the Menu component, you are setting the state `selectedDish`. If you are trying to set the state in parent component, you might want to change the `onDishSelect` of Menu component as:

```
onDishSelect(dishId) {
  this.props.onClick(dishId);
}
```

Pass the function as prop to the child component as:

```
/*Main.js */

    <Menu
      dishes={this.state.dishes}
      selectedDish={this.state.selectedDish}
      onClick={this.onDishSelect}
    />
```

As a suggestion, you're setting the `selectedDish`in the parent/Main component and is accessible in Menu as `this.props.selectedDish`, so it is redundant to set the same in the Menu as well.
You can replace all the `this.state.selectedDish` the Menu with `this.props.selectedDish`.

Comment: I have tried this in the Menu component but it keeps showing that this.props.onClick is not a function!

Comment: Thats intresting, will be helpful if there is a fiddle. Meanwhile can you try converting it to arrow function like `onDishSelect = (dishId)  =>  this.setState({ selectedDish: dishId })`